# Can't connect to RDS database using psql client?

Tags: amazon-rds

Could you please explain my situation? I have a Virtual Private Cloud (VPC) that contains both a private subnet and a database subnet (which is also private). Within the private subnet, I have located my backend server, while the database subnet is designated for my database instances.

When I attempt to access my database by SSH-ing into my backend server, it works perfectly fine. However, when I try to use the psql client to connect to my database, it shows a 'pending' state. I have verified that my database's security group allows all traffic to its ports, and my database subnet already has a NAT gateway enabled. Where could the issue be originating from?

Comment: Hi @windadapt. This question is not a programming question, rather a configuration question. As such I suspect it is likelier to be answered in [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/). That being said, I'd check security groups and the VPC network ACL attached to the subnets to see if you can access the RDS server.